# How to add background image at the login page?

Tags: laravel

so there is this project iam working on..now i want to add a background image at the login page....i have tried to upload the photo on the public/background folder...then in the css file i have created the directory but so far no changes!!

now my project look like below ..i have uploaded an image named backgroung.jpg on background folder but also in public/background and /public_html/vendors/gauge.js/assets then at my css file html {
background_image:url('public/background/background.jpg')} so far no changes

```
accountant
app
background
bootstrap
build
config
css
customer
database
employee
garage
garragelogo
general_setting
img
js
.
.
.

html {
background_image:url('public/background/background.jpg')}
```

i expected a lot i guess help please ......

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your path relatively like this `../../../public/background/background.jpg` which `../` is a backward directory

or you can set your background in your html tag like this
`<html style="background: {{ asset('background/background.jpg') }}">`

hope it helps

Comment: it didnt work but wen i inspect the project and edit my css file it works i used 
        background-image: url('public/general_settings/background1.jpg')      but sadly when i update it on cpanel it doesnt work

Comment: but i did set    <body style="background-image: URL('public/general_setting/background1.jpg')">  and it worked thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use this code block for setting background image on any page.

```html
<div class="classToDefineBackgroundSetCss" style="background-image: url('{{asset('assets/bg-slider/bg-slider1.jpg')}}');">
<form>
 <!-- LOGIN FORM -->
</form>                                    
</div>
```